# Finding ANOVA table and 95% CI in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I'm trying to run the ANOVA on the bone marrow transplant study at Ohio State University.

Here is the data using the code from( [Cox proportional hazard model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919837/cox-proportional-hazard-model/60921594?noredirect=1#comment107815473_60921594) ).

```
time_Allo_NHL<- c(28,32,49,84,357,933,1078,1183,1560,2114,2144)
censor_Allo_NHL<- c(rep(1,5), rep(0,6))
df_Allo_NHL <- data.frame(group = "Allo NHL", 
                          time = time_Allo_NHL,
                          censor = censor_Allo_NHL,
                          Z1 = c(90,30,40,60,70,90,100,90,80,80,90),
                          Z2 = c(24,7,8,10,42,9,16,16,20,27,5))

time_Auto_NHL<- c(42,53,57,63,81,140,176,210,252,476,524,1037)
censor_Auto_NHL<- c(rep(1,7), rep(0,1), rep(1,1), rep(0,1), rep(1,1), rep(0,1))
df_Auto_NHL <- data.frame(group = "Auto NHL", 
                          time = time_Auto_NHL, 
                          censor = censor_Auto_NHL,
                          Z1 = c(80,90,30,60,50,100,80,90,90,90,90,90),
                          Z2 = c(19,17,9,13,12,11,38,16,21,24,39,84))

time_Allo_HOD<- c(2,4,72,77,79)
censor_Allo_HOD<- c(rep(1,5))
df_Allo_HOD <- data.frame(group = "Allo HOD", 
                          time = time_Allo_HOD, 
                          censor = censor_Allo_HOD,
                          Z1 = c(20,50,80,60,70),
                          Z2 = c(34,28,59,102,71))

time_Auto_HOD<- c(30,36,41,52,62,108,132,180,307,406,446,484,748,1290,1345)
censor_Auto_HOD<- c(rep(1,7), rep(0,8))
df_Auto_HOD <- data.frame(group = "Auto HOD", 
                          time = time_Auto_HOD, 
                          censor = censor_Auto_HOD,
                          Z1 = c(90,80,70,60,90,70,60,100,100,100,100,90,90,90,80),
                          Z2 = c(73,61,34,18,40,65,17,61,24,48,52,84,171,20,98))

myData <- Reduce(rbind, list(df_Allo_NHL, df_Auto_NHL, df_Allo_HOD, df_Auto_HOD))
```

Then I used the cox ph:

```
myData<- Reduce(rbind, list(df_Allo_NHL, df_Auto_NHL, df_Allo_HOD, df_Auto_HOD))
myData

library(survival)

for(i in 1:43){
  if (myData$group[i]=="Auto NHL")
    myData$Z1[i]<-1
  else myData$Z1[i]<-0
}

for(i in 1:43){
  if (myData$group[i]=="Allo HOD")
    myData$Z2[i]<-1
  else myData$Z2[i]<-0
}

for(i in 1:43){
  if (myData$group[i]=="Auto HOD")
    myData$Z3[i]<-1
  else myData$Z3[i]<-0
}

myData

Coxfit<-coxph(Surv(time,censor)~Z1+Z2+Z3, data = myData)
summary(Coxfit)
```

Then,1- I want to obtain the ANOVA. 
How can I do that including (DF, Parameter Estimates, Standard Error, Chi-square and p-value) in the results?

The values should be as follows:
[image]

2- How can I obtain the ANOVA of the disease type by transplant interaction?

The interaction was obtained as follows, from ( [Cox proportional hazard model-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957057/cox-proportional-hazard-model-interaction) ):

```
library(tidyr)
myData <- separate(myData, col=group, into=c("disease","transpl"))
head(myData)



Coxfit.W<-coxph(Surv(time,censor)~transplant_type*disease_type, data = myData)
summary(Coxfit.W)
```

The values should be as follows:

[image]

3- How to get point estimates and 95% CI for the relative risk of death for an NHL Auto transplant patient as compared to an NHL Allo transplant patient?

The results shoud be: 1.94 with a 95% CI of (0.64, 5.87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, the parameters are in `coefficients(Coxfit)` and the anova can be obtained by `anova(Coxfit)`, you can try:

```
aovres = anova(Coxfit)
cbind(paramter = coefficients(Coxfit),aovres[-1,c(3,2,4)])

    paramter Df      Chisq  Pr(>|Chi|)
Z1 0.6422532  1 0.38223478 0.536409640
Z2 1.8212306  1 7.31476152 0.006839047
Z3 0.1584653  1 0.07297854 0.787048385
```

For 2, you can relevel the factors:

```
splitData <- separate(myData, col=group, into=c("disease","transpl"))
splitData$transpl = factor(splitData$transpl,levels=c("NHL","HOD"))
Coxfit.W<-coxph(Surv(time,censor)~transpl*disease, data = splitData)
```

If you check the summary, it gives you the coefficients you need (as in the intended odds ratio) in the anova:

```
summary(Coxfit.W)

                           coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)   
transplHOD              1.82123   6.17946  0.67473  2.699  0.00695 **
diseaseAuto             0.64225   1.90076  0.56415  1.138  0.25493   
transplHOD:diseaseAuto -2.30502   0.09976  0.84938 -2.714  0.00665 **

cbind(paramter = coefficients(Coxfit.W),anova(Coxfit.W)[-1,c(3,2,4)])
```

For 3., this it might be easier to use your original data.frame with "group", so you set the reference level to be "NHL allo" and all the odds ratio will be relative to this:

```
myData$group = factor(myData$group,levels=c("Allo NHL","Auto NHL","Allo HOD","Auto HOD"))

summary(coxph(Surv(time,censor)~group, data = myData))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, censor) ~ group, data = myData)

  n= 43, number of events= 26 

                coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
groupAuto NHL 0.6423    1.9008   0.5641 1.138  0.25493   
groupAllo HOD 1.8212    6.1795   0.6747 2.699  0.00695 **
groupAuto HOD 0.1585    1.1717   0.5889 0.269  0.78785   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

              exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
groupAuto NHL     1.901     0.5261    0.6291     5.743
groupAllo HOD     6.179     0.1618    1.6467    23.189
groupAuto HOD     1.172     0.8535    0.3695     3.716
```

You have the odds ratio under "groupAuto NHL".. (not very clear why it differs from what you expect)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to do ANOVA for part 2?

Comment: you just do Coxfit.W<-coxph(Surv(time,censor)~transpl*disease, data = splitData) ; anova(Coxfit.W) ? The terms may look different but they are essentially testing the same thing, if you look at the degree of freedom

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting an error. Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'transpl' not found

Comment: ok.. you have this step, myData<- Reduce(rbind, list(df_Allo_NHL, df_Auto_NHL, df_Allo_HOD, df_Auto_HOD)) , from here, you have to keep this for analysis 3 and create another data.frame for analysis 2

Comment: so myData<- Reduce(rbind, list(df_Allo_NHL, df_Auto_NHL, df_Allo_HOD, df_Auto_HOD)); splitData <- separate(myData, col=group, into=c("disease","transpl")) ; splitData$transpl = factor(splitData$transpl,levels=c("NHL","HOD"))
Coxfit.W<-coxph(Surv(time,censor)~transpl*disease, data = splitData)